# Magit - How to drop all stashes at once?

Tags: magit, git

I have created quite a few stashes and I wanted to drop all of them at once.

From terminal I could have done

```
git stash clear
```

I couldn't find a way to do it from magit.

I tried selecting all stashes and drop, but that didn't work.

Comment: Magit recently had a major update, make sure you are running version 2.1 or you may see a large disparity between how your magit and other user's magit behaves.

Comment: I had the same problem. I uninstalled the package I had from melpa and suddenly 2.1.0 was available for me to install and it wasn't before. Now everything is working as expected. @ChillarAnand, try to uninstall and install magit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes that you are using Magit v2.1 or greater, and it very much sounds like you are using an older version. So start by updating Magit.

---

If you want to drop more than one stash at a time, select all the stashes using the region and press <kbd>k</kbd>. It will ask you if you want to "drop N stashes?".

Another way to drop them all is by putting your cursor on the Stashes header and pressing <kbd>k</kbd>. (If you want to delete *all* stashes, then you should use this method, because it is more efficient than the other, which drops each stash individually.)

Answer (score 0):

After browsing source code, I just wrote a function and it works fine

```lisp
(defun magit-stash-clear ()
  "Magit - drop all stashes."
  (interactive)
  (magit-run-git "stash" "clear"))
```

Comment: I ended up doing that. The odd thing is that in magit's source code (https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/master/lisp/magit-stash.el#L163) looks like it is supported although I could not make it work either.

Comment: @RafadeCastro I re-opened an issue for that https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1926